# Taxonomy fields in node default display using display suite

Tags: views, display-suite

I have a content type called "product" and a taxonomy called "producer".
On each product, I can select a producer.
The producer has some fields I need: "country", "area", "district".

I need to display those 3 fields from the producer on the product default display.
How can I do that?

---

Some things I tried that don't work:

- Created a view pane with a contextual filter for term id, then selected the argument input to be "From context" and selected the producer field from the product.
- Created a dynamic field in ds and selected the view pane and selected "No being viewd" as the argument.

Answer (score 0):

In Manage display of Product content type, select **Rendered taxonomy term** for term reference producer, then create `taxonoy-term--producer.tpl.php` to change style of the taxonomy.